# Bind onclickevent for a dynamically added jQuery element

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, dynamically-generated

Could you please advise how to bind a onclick function for a dymanically added iframe element in JQuery.

The situation is like - I have got 4 radio buttons. Whenever somebody is selecting the second radio button I am loading one iframe and there is a button in that iframe where I need to have one onclick function from an external JS file.

on page load $("#iframe").length = 0, so could not use the $("#iframe").find method.

Please advise

Thanks,
Aniket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the iFrame with a valid selector and use `.contents()` to get its content.

```
var iframe = $('#your_iframe').contents();

iframe.find('your_clicable_item').click(function(event){
   console.log('work fine');
});
```

Comment: Hi Manish, Thanks for your reply. I have tried this one but its not working as on page load the iframe is still not available. it will work only after the radio button selection